# PXSelect not bringing back recently persisted rows

Tags: acumatica

I am writing an override for CalculateSalesPriceInt() (The function that calculates the sale price for an item) Here is the code in question

```
        [PXOverride]
    public virtual decimal? CalculateSalesPriceInt(PXCache sender, string custPriceClass, int? customerID, int? inventoryID, int? siteID, CurrencyInfo currencyinfo, decimal? quantity, string UOM, DateTime date, bool alwaysFromBaseCurrency,
         Func<PXCache, string, int?, int?, int?, CurrencyInfo, decimal?, string, DateTime, bool, decimal?> del)
    {
        Customer cust =
            PXSelect<Customer, Where<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Required<Customer.bAccountID>>>>.Select(
                Base, customerID);
        InventoryItem item =
            PXSelect<InventoryItem,
                    Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>>
                .Select(Base, inventoryID);
        var itemExt = item.GetExtension<Arctc001InventoryItem>();
        var custExt = cust.GetExtension<Arctc001Customer>();
```

The issue is with the InventoryItem and Customer selects. The process is such:

- Create new sales order for a customer
- Insert Item A into SOLines
- Decide I dont like the Descr(or any other field) for item A and click on the hyperlink to pop open an instance of the StockItemMaint Page
- Edit the Descr Field so it is different
- Press Save and close the StockItemMaint page
- Delete said InventoryItem from SOLines
- Re-Add the same InventoryItem back in
- Calculate SalesPriceInt fires off as I add the item back in
- In debug mode, take a look at the results of PXSelect and even though I have Persisted my changes in the window, the old values still come up.

I have tried using either PXSelect or PXSelectReadonly, and no matter what the old values before I changed the inventoryitem record still come back as a result

How can I work with the cache so I get these persisted values?

Thanks

Comment: You are using 2 different graphs and made changes on on graph 2 while graph 1 was still open. You will need to refresh the page for graph 1 or clear the query cache to possible get the new results. This sounds better to just have the user refresh the page or you will just clear the cache for all orders all the time making the cache useless on sales order which would benefit from not having the cache cleared. This goes for any 2 graphs open. To get the updated results you need to refresh the page if the change occurred in a different graph.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Even after a page refresh it takes nearly logging out and back in again for it to refresh the cache, ill just communicate how things work so there are no surprises to the end user.

Comment: You can also execute graph.Clear(PXClearOption.ClearQueriesOnly); before executing select. It will give you new data. However, it affects performance of the solution